# Is there any free host which supports php and mySQL in utf-8?

Tags: php, mysql, free, web-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

Is there any **free host** which supports php and **mySQL queries in utf-8**?
I've already tried to use x10hosting and 000webhosting, but they don't support utf8 mysql queries (got mojibake). The default encoding of mysql in both sites is latin-1, and you're not able to change that.

Is there any other **free host that fully supports utf-8**?

Comment: It looks like a duplicate, but the answer is different. You don't have to change your provider, tell the database at runtime what you expect. If you are using mysqli you could use this line `$mysqli_db->set_charset("utf8");` to define the output of the queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

www.bplaced.net
I have never tried it, but they offer phpmyadmin, so you can change settings manually. By the way, have you tried "set names 'utf8'"? E.g.:

```
$db=mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password);
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_select_db($db_database, $db);
```

Comment: Alternatively, if you don't need to perform UTF string comparisons/manipulations in the database, you could just use a different encoding (e.g. punycode) for storage or simply store it as binary data. Also, you can use a single-byte character set like Latin-1 (ISO-8859) as an intermediate encoding. So display the text as UTF-8, but when you write to or query the database, just let MySQL treat the UTF-8 strings as Latin-1 strings. In most cases it shouldn't cause any problems as long as you stick to simple string functions (i.e. don't use `TRIM` or `CONVERT` or other charset-sensitive methods).

Comment: Though I'd still try to do most of your string manipulation in PHP just to be safe.

Comment: might want to look into this one. never used it myself but a couple of my mates have - http://www.freevirtualservers.com/